# 固定widthの親要素内の子要素でmin-width指定

Tags: html, css

固定widthの親要素内で、子要素のmin-widthを指定してmin-width〜親のwidth内でスケールさせたいのですが、以下のコードだと子要素がmin-widthを無視して親要素と同じ幅になってしまいます。
どなたか解決策をご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教示ください。

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

.parent {
    width: 500px;
}
.child {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` 要素の標準は `display: block` なので、何も指定しないと幅は親要素一杯に広がります。[`display` プロパティ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/display)を `inline-block` や `table` などにすると、中身に応じて幅が伸縮します。

```css
.parent {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: darkblue;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 500px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">child 1</div>
    <div class="child">child 2 ##################################</div>
    <div class="child">
        child 3
        =====================================================
    </div>
</div>
```